# Setting React children typescript definition breaks parent props type checking

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to work out why setting the children prop for React/JSX components break the type-checking of the parent component.

The simple code example is shown below, if I do not define the children type the top Test fails to show an error on the `someOtherProp`, if I define the children prop then the second Test component fails to show an error on the `someOtherProp`, if I make children optional, then it fails on both components.

```
import React from 'react';

export interface TestProps {
  style: {
    flex?: number;
  };
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Test = ({ style }: TestProps) => <div style={style} />;

export const MainTest = () => (
  <>
    <Test style={{ flex: 1, someOtherProp: 'center' }} />;
    <Test style={{ flex: 1, someOtherProp: 'center' }}>
      <p>Children Breaks TypeChecking</p>
    </Test>
  </>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed upgrading from typescript version 3.4.5 to 3.5.1.